# Turning off toggleClass when any other link clicked?

Tags: jquery, toggle, toggleclass

I have this toggle sliding open a menu and adding an active class to let you know its open, i've cobbled this together and there is a glitch..

```
$(".parents-toggle > a").click(function () {
          $(this).toggleClass('active');
         $(".parents-toggle > ul.sub-menu").not($(this).siblings()).slideUp();
         $(this).siblings(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
      });

      $(".parents-toggle-inner > a").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
         $(".parents-toggle-inner > ul.sub-menu").not($(this).siblings()).slideUp();
         $(this).siblings(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
      });​
```

It stays active if you click any other button as well, so staying active unless you close it....

Is it possible to remove the active class if you click any other link on the page? So even if there is a another toggle menu separate to this one, so any link ideally..?

http://jsfiddle.net/24k5U/2/

As you can see you get a mass of orange/active buttons

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: You should remove 'active' class for all elements before adding one is clicked. I updated your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/eYrvd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `$('.active').removeClass('active');` in the click event. That should fix it.

That way, you code now becomes:

```
$(".parents-toggle > a").click(function () {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');  // <---- This line added
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(".parents-toggle > ul.sub-menu").not($(this).siblings()).slideUp();
    $(this).siblings(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
});
```

Basically, what you are doing is making sure that there are no links with `class=active` before you `toggleClass()` the clicked link.

You can do the same thing to inner or sub links.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class from other elements at the same level before you apply it to any others:

```
  $(".parents-toggle > a").click(function () {
      $(".parents-toggle > a").removeClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      $(".parents-toggle > ul.sub-menu").not($(this).siblings()).slideUp();
      $(this).siblings(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
  });
```

Comment: Brilliant! This 99% it, would it be possible for an inner menu to turn off too? e.g http://jsfiddle.net/24k5U/7/ click grand parents and all within then another parent, the inner child remains active :(

Comment: @roasted Why use unnecessary selectors?

Comment: @user4630 Yes, the approach is similar, but I'll add the code if you want

Comment: Yes please if that would be possible, just trying to remove all active classes when you move onto another section/menu.

Comment: @Asad, in fact you are correct as :first filter an already existing list of elements, so its worse to use it, good point!

Comment: @user4630 What I don't understand is why you have a `Child Button` and a `Parent Button` that are siblings.

Comment: This might explain it a little more... http://jsfiddle.net/24k5U/10/ There will be multiple separate menus, i've just tried to simplify it down...